# 256 KB in cache size is really 256 KiB?

Tags: caching, memory-management, size

So, I am confused regarding the whole KB /KiB concept.
I read in a datasheet that a specific L2 cache has 256KB capacity. From other sources I have read the size to be 256 kB.

Sometimes when people write KB, or kB, they mean KiB, and sometimes not. My limited knowledge about memory leads me to believe that cache sizes should be a power of two bytes.

In the context of cache size, is it more likely that the size of the memory is 256 000 bytes or 2^10*256= 262 144 bytes?

Edit: Not the actual datasheet, but as an example have a look at the L1 cache on this AMD processor.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:AMD_A64_Opteron_arch.svg

Comment: A kilobyte is 1024 bytes. 256 kilobytes is 262,144 bytes.

Comment: The 262144 number is more likely, although (very unlikely) some non functional memory could be unused to increase yield. That technique is is used for flash drives, but afaik not normally for cache ram.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've got:

- RAM (always comes in powers of 2 sizes)
- "256" (a power of 2)
- capital K in "KB" (the standard is lowercase k = 1000, so capital K often implies the non-standard units)

All 3 of these things imply binary sizes, so yes, it's safe to assume they meant 256 kilobinary bytes = 256 KiB = 256×1024 B = 262,144 bytes.

Yes, writing it as "KB" is non-standard and confusing and wrong, but it's unfortunately common, so you need to use context to figure out what is actually meant.

Comment: Good on you to find this old question.

Answer (score 1):

Read these: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kibibyte

Technical documentation and code generally uses the power of two sizes because of the underlying binary system. But often... for historical reasons... the unit is written as MB instead of MiB, or KB/kB instead KiB.

If you see something looking like a power of two, like ..., 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, ... it is very likely to be a binary size.

Answer (score 0):

Without a reference to the specific data sheet you're talking about, it's hard to make a judgement.

In general, when talking about hardware these are powers of 2, thus 262144.

The base-10 version is mostly used around disk storage, where mere mortals pay less attention to detail.

Comment: It's just RAM that's measured in powers of 2, not "hardware".  Networking hardware is measured in powers of 10, flash drive sizes are measured in powers of 10, etc.

Comment: only for marketing who want to inflate their numbers.  Techies use powers of 2.  Back in the day, we used to get very upset when HD manufacturers started using powers of 10 to describe drive sizes.

Comment: I doubt it.  HD manufacturers have used powers of 10 to describe drive sizes since they first started selling drives to the public.  When do you think they changed?  Do you remember an actual date, or a specific product?  Likewise, networking engineers have always used powers of 10 to describe data rates, and electrical engineers have always measured digital logic clock rates in powers of 10.  Using powers of 2 for RAM sizes is fine, since they come in powers of 2, but abusing SI notation for that purpose is not fine, especially since it is not abused in other computing contexts.

Comment: Disks started using powers of 10 in 1993.  I was working at Egghead Software at the time (which sold hardware too, kinda), and it was around then the shift started happening, and there was a lot of hooplah around capacity.  I took a lot of flack from customers who said "why does my OS report < 100 MB?" 1.44 MB floppes are measured in powers of 2, for instance...

Comment: The IBM 3340/3344 Disk Storage was marketed in 1973 as "70-megabyte" and held 69,889,536 bytes of data [67 MiB].  Can you give an example of a hard drive that was marketed using powers of 2 between 1973 and 1993? The OS reported the wrong size because Microsoft uses non-standard units.  1.44 MB floppies were not measured in powers of 2; they held 1.44 * 1000 * 1024 bytes, a bizarre mixture of both conventions.

Comment: Ok.  Marketing guys have been douches for a long time.  The answer is still mostly correct according to the OP question: "When dealing with RAM, how many bytes are in 256KB?"

Comment: Yes, they certainly have been.  It could even be argued that the K=1024 convention is the invention of marketing guys.  Donald Morrison's 1968 letter to the editor talks of "doubling the size of a 32K memory and getting 65K (not 64K) memories", and that while engineers understand this, it's confusing to outsiders, and proposed the adoption of a new unit for 1024 that would allow 32+32=64.  Sounds like the marketing guys just reused K instead and ran with it.

Answer (score -2):

As far as I know, it is mainly the (Sales guys at) disk drive manufacturers that use kiB and MiB, real engineers use powers of 2 :-)

Comment: Why the downvote without explanation? If you know better, please enlighten the rest of us.